# Is it possible to communicate between electron browser and form application window?

Tags: winforms, electron

I'm newbie to **"Electron"** framework:
I need to create a POC showing communication between "Electron" browser window and a local windows forms application. I'm aware that the "Electron" has abilities of "investigating" the machine and maybe even understand what apps (form application, in my case) are up. I'm aware of the inter process communication (IPC) it has, but it doesn't seems to help me.
I would like to know if I have the ability to click on a button in the "Electron" Browser window (BrowserWindow) and make some response (write to a text box, for example) in an up and running form application.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

IPC is only for communicating within Electron's main process and render process. It can't be used to let Electron talk to other applications (like Firefox for example). Electron is basically a chromium browser that uses NodeJS to interact with local OS resources.

I am not sure it is possible to do what you want to do unless you create custom [Addons](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) in C/C++ to sit between the OS and all running applications. If that isn't your thing, check NPM for something that might exist already.

Out of the box, the closest things you will get are Node's [Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and [command line options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html), but they won't do what you want them to do based on my understanding of your question.